# Are files in other drives erased when a new O.S. is installed in a drive?

Tags: windows, multi-boot

Currently I have Windows 7 installed on the `C:` Drive, and I want to dual-boot Windows 10 in the same drive. Will files in the `D:` and `E:` drives get affected in this process, or they are totally safe?

Comment: Your files on D & E should be fine, as long as you are careful what you mess with in the installation process(es) of the two operating systems. You are in control, the installation processes will let you erase and obliterate every piece of data in your box if you tell it to, or leave it all alone. Read carefully and double check everything. My primary concern would be installing Win 10 concurrently with Windows 7, you will need to do some partition resizing and possibly reinstalling, Windows Installer doesn't like to share disks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to dual boot, You will need to resize the C: partition, which will create a new partition F: and install Windows 10 on it, otherwise the installation will only install Windows 10 and you will have an 'old' windows folder in C: drive. D: and E: will not be affected, **provided you do not mess with them during installation**. Ensure yo choose the "Custom Install" during the Windows 10 installation.